# Is object guaranteed to be initialized before calling its member function?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49814895/why-doesnt-calling-member-function-invoke-the-odr-use-of-that-object) (still not solved) I come across this new problem,so here I made an example:

```
//main.cpp  

int main() {
    return 0;
}

//file1.cpp
#include "b.h"
B b;

//file2.cpp
#include "a.h"
A a;

//a.h
#pragma once
#include<iostream>
#include "b.h"
extern B b;
class A
{
public:
    A(){ std::cout << "a cotr" << std::endl;b.Use(); }
};

//b.h
#pragma once
#include<iostream>
class B
{
public:
    B() { std::cout << "b ctor"<<std::endl; };
    void Use() { std::cout << "use b" << std::endl; }
};
```

In g++ 6.3.0 the output is:( g++ -o test file1.cpp file2.cpp prac.cpp -std=c++11)
a cotr
**use b**
b ctor

So from the code example it seems that there's no such guarantee,and probably is an **undefined behavior** ?Is there anywhere the standard said about this?(I do not think it's a duplicate because this situation is a little different:in the initialization of `a`,invoke `b`'s member function.)

Comment: You'd probably want to read [this](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order) too

Comment: @PasserBy I read that,but this situation is a little different,because in the initialization of `a`,invoke `b`'s member function.

Comment: @bigxiao invoking member function does not affect object creation, it is already created or not.

Comment: @Slava So is the `b.Use()`  invoking **undefined behavior** ?

Comment: @bigxiao if constructor have not been called yet then yes it is UB. Order of initialization of global objects in different compilation units is implementation specific.

Comment: I agree this is a duplicate.  Calling a member function rather than using the value is neither here nor there.

Comment: @MartinBonner What if we access `b`'s member object in `Use()`, or in `a`'s constructor?

Comment: @bigxiao accessing a member has no effect on when an object is initialized.

Comment: @user2079303 I'm just responding to what he said about "using the value".

Comment: "using the value" was in the context of the other question, where the objects are primitive types.  Calling a member function of `b` *uses* `b`, and is UB before `b` is constructed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is object guaranteed to be initialized before calling its member function?

No, it is your job not to call any non-static member function on invalid object, that includes but not limited to passing `nullptr` as `this`, object not created yet or already destroyed object. One of the solution of this situation is to have static local object in a function instead of global one and return reference/pointer to it. That method still have problem with destruction order, but at least half of the problem is gone.

Comment: So you mean that calling non-static member function of `obj.foo()` before `obj` is construted is undefined behavior?What about static member fuction?

Comment: Static member functions are fine (they are basically no different to a global function) as long as they don't access any static member variables which aren't yet initialised.